# Loading large models on iPad

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to develop an iPad app, which loads a model, reads the properties from model and build some logic on top of the properties. I tried to load different size models(revit), and tried to load the properties of all elements using getBulkProperties(), as well as getProprties(). These functions works fine for small size models, but for large models it simply returns undefined. I have tried to bind object tree created event, but it never gets fired in case of large models on iPad, Is there any way to load the properties for large models on iPad, and is there any difference on loading the properties from a linked model and a normal model?

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested strictly in the properties of a model, there are other ways of retrieving the metadata, likely more efficient than using the Viewer APIs. Please see this blog post for more details: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer. You could for example retrieve all properties in form of a sqlite database, and process the metadata that way.

Regarding the other question (whether there's any difference between "normal" models and "linked" models), the Model Derivative service is extracting properties from "main" and "linked" models in the same way.

Comment: this helps. Just one follow up question, Currently it  is possible to get the bounding box of elements using viewer instance, but is it possible to fetch bounding boxes of elements using some API, without loading the model in viewer?

Comment: Yep, that's possible, too. Bounding boxes are stored as part of each "fragment" in the SVF model. The SVF format is not publicly documented, unfortunately, but there's a library that helps you parse it: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils. The actual code parsing the bboxes is [here](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils/blob/develop/src/svf/fragments.ts#L32-L34).